# Ubuntu not booting: "Could not write bytes: broken pipes"

Tags: boot, apt, updates

**The problem** When I boot Ubuntu 11.10, the boot process hangs, before even getting to the login screen of the display manager, with the message

```
Could not write bytes: broken pipes
```

at the top of the screen, followed by some lines of text (where one yellow star left of "PulseAudio" is - don't know if this is important...), the last being

```
* Stopping System V runlevel compatability                                          [Ok]
```

After that I can only press Ctrl+Alt+Del to reboot.

**The cause** The problem occured after I did an update on feb., the 18th. In the process of the update a window popped up in which I had to choose the default display manager. Being in a hurry, I just clicked "ok" (gdm was the default selection in that window). Afterwards I found out that Ubuntu 11.10 us es lightdm so I figured, that maybe this was the cause of my problem. Before this update everything worked fine.

**{What I tried so far to do to fix it [skip this, if its too long]** I logged in as root in recovery mode and tried to reinstall lightdm. Using the apt-get command I get error that spans over 3 lines of text, the first of which is

```
Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock;
```

but I don't know of any process that is using apt-get, that is preventing it from being run.

After that I used  `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`  and selected lightdm as the default display manager. This exited with the line

```
mv: cannot move 'etc/X11/default-display-manager' to '/etc/X11/default-display-manager.pdkg-tmp': Read-only file system".
```

When I then booted in normal mode it still hung, but the message `Could not write bytes: broken pipes` was gone, there were just two lines of text, the first said something about the battery state and the last was identical to the one above ("* Stopping System V[...]"). I played around a little bit by also trying `dpkg-reconfigure gdm`
and choosing gdm instead of lightdm, but none of that helped. The system still hangs, just with different lines of text showing up, but "* Stopping System V[...]" is always the last one. **}**

**Other info** This may be or not be relevant: I use multiple operating systems (the other ones work) and the kernel I use is 3.0.0-15-generic-pae.

Please help, I invested so much time in setting my Ubuntu system up, I don't want to do it all over again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, what's going on is when you go into recovery your disks are mounted as read-only. I just did this and for some reason the Mount Disk option didn't work, so I just hit the 'root' option and used:

```
mount -o remount,rw,errors=remount-ro /
```

This makes your drive writable. Once you do that you should be able to do your `dkpkg-reconfigure lightdm`

If it still says "read-only filesystem" then do the opposite and start a disk check:

```
mount -o remount,ro /
rootpartition=$(cat /etc/fstab | grep -E "# / was on .*installation" | awk '{print $5}')
e2fsck $rootpartition
```

If you can't remember that big long `rootpartition=` string, you can also get the device by going to /dev/disk/by-uuid use the file that is a big 36-character string (it should be the only one if you don't have any other Ext partitions). So, it would look something like this (using my UUID): `fsck /dev/disk/by-uuid/062b52ee-5df4-4ad2-829e-0734f822748c`

If any errors are found, be sure to restart!

In fact, I had this exact same problem when trying to nuke Unity and uninstalling unity-greeter (even though lightdm was still installed). I think it removed /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf but left /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf (which has a reference to unity-greeter.conf) unchanged. That makes sense why it wouldn't boot, though I didn't think to look and just re-installed unity-greeter once I worked my way past the read-only issue I was having.

Anyway, give it a shot!

Comment: Hey, thanks a million times, doing in root  first `mount -o remount,rw,errors=remount-ro /`  and then `dkpk-reconfigure lightdm` worked! (Wish I could upvote, but I have to few reps) Do you have any idea though, why it now takes well over 30 seconds until ubuntu gets from the login to desktop, whereas earlier it took at most 7 ?

Comment: Probably because ureadahead was re-profiling. Anytime you modify a package involved in the start-up ureadahead (the boot caching program) has to re-make its database. Subsequent restarts should be well improved.