# Could not write bytes: broken pipe

Tags: filesystem

1. What does this message displayed on a black screen before the login prompt mean?
2. Should it be cause for concern?
3. How should I respond to it?

I have one network drive, and two internal drives; one EXT4, one NTFS.

Comment: Isn't there any more output related to it? What process does it concern? And where exactly do you read that message? In a log file, GUI dialog, in the splash screen....

Comment: Such error message may appear in many places. Depending on context it may describe different problems. Please provide as many details to your question as it is possible.

Comment: I got this same error message after installing Linux Mint alongside Ubuntu and Windows 7. I'm using a Lenovo Z560 laptop.

Answer (score 1):

- *What does this message displayed on a black screen before the login prompt mean*?

It's a Plymouth thing, what does it mean I do not know I can't find anything conclusive, seems [network related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584904/what-causes-the-broken-pipe-error).

- *Should it be cause for concern?, How should I respond to it?*

Just ignore it, I used to get that message too nothing wrong happened.

If something does happen, try what it says [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105857/ubuntu-11-10-not-booting-could-not-write-bytes-broken-pipes) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129888/crash-during-12-04-upgrade-broken-pipe-cannot-boot).

Comment: I think it is caused by the network shares too, but I wanted confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error message when rebooting my computer. To fix it, I just turned my computer off and on, and the second time I did not receive the error message and was taken right to the login screen. I have Ubuntu 12.04 dual booted with Windows 7.